# How can I set a rotation point for an element in CSS?

Tags: css, css-transforms

Is it possible to set the rotation point in CSS? The default rotation point is at the 50%, 50%.
I tried:

```
transform: rotate(230deg); 
rotation-point:90% 90%;
```

But it does not work... Any suggestions?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

This will set the rotation pivot point on top-left corner of your element and rotate it:

```
transform: rotate(-25deg);
transform-origin: 0% 0%;
```

take a glance at `.nav_item_txt` class:

http://jsfiddle.net/KHkX7/

Comment: thanks you so much. and now 2024 it still working as well

Answer (score 17):

Use the [transform-origin](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-2d-transforms/#transform-origin-property) CSS property:

```
.class {
    transform-origin: 0 0;
}
```

Answer (score 10):

Try using the transform-origin property instead, rotation-point isn't supported...

For rotating on the top right point of an element (including all targeting):

```
-webkit-transform-origin: 100% 0;
-moz-transform-origin: 100% 0;
-ms-transform-origin: 100% 0;
-o-transform-origin: 100% 0;
transform-origin: 100% 0;
```

Answer (score -2):

just go to http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_rotation-point.asp and read carefully.
it says that none of the major browsers support this property.

Comment: never never never trust w3schools... is a really bad source of information http://www.w3fools.com/

Comment: @ncubica W3schools is actually right on this one. "rotation" and "rotation-point" aren't supported. Rotation isn't used directly but through transforms together with transform-origin as indicated in the correct answer.

Comment: 2021 update, read again w3fool.com I posted my previous message in 2014 long long time ago :)