# How can I change the pivot on my rotateZ animation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-transitions, css-transforms

I have this simple html code :

```
  <div class='d'>
     <span>  1234567890 </span>
    <input type='button' class='b'/>
  </div>
```

When a button is clicked , I apply this style :

```
.dropped span
{
 transform: translateZ(200px )  rotatez(120deg);
 color:red;
 transition: all 1.3s ease-in;
}
```

via

```
$(".b").on('click',function (){
    $(".d").addClass('dropped')
})
```

So here is the result :

[image]

**Question**

I don't want it to be rotated on the `6` digit.

I want it to be rotated on the `1` digit.

How can I do that ?

[**JSBIN**](http://jsbin.com/mamiqu/5/edit)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Set rotation point in CSS3?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6652476/set-rotation-point-in-css3)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify the `transform-origin` to `0 50%;`.
Note that transforms normaly [don't apply on inline elements](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-transforms-1/#terminology) like `<span>` so I changed it's display property to `inline-block;` :

```js
$(".b").on('click', function() {
  $(".d").addClass('dropped')
})
```

```css
.d {
  font-family: 'Orbitron', sans-serif;
  /* font style. Default uses Google fonts */
  text-shadow: 2px 2px #B4EAF3, 3px 3px #B4EAF3, 4px 4px #B4EAF3, 5px 5px #B4EAF3, 6px 6px #B4EAF3;
  font-size: 4vw;
  color: #207688;
  letter-spacing: 15px;
  font-weight: 800;
  position: relative;
}
.d span {
  display: inline-block;
  transform-origin: 0 50%;
}
.dropped span {
  transform: rotate(120deg);
  color: red;
  transition: all 1.3s ease-in;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='d'>
  <span>  1234567890 </span>
  <input type='button' class='b' />
</div>
```

More info on the `transform-origin` property on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin)

Comment: so how come the rotate did work without inline-block ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir I have already come across this and some browsers still apply transforms on inline elements which doesn' follow web standards. But in my browser, the transform origin doesn't work when the element is inline.