# Refresh icon rotate but not around his center

Tags: html, css

I have a `<table>` and I need to put rotating refresh icon inside any `<td>` till I got the value of the `<td>`.
The problem is the icon not correctly rotating around the center.
check the code below.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var appendhtml = '<span class="refreshing"><i class="material-icons">refresh</i></span>';
  $('.main').find('tr').eq(1).find('td').eq(2).html(appendhtml);
});
```

```css
th {
  text-align: left;
}

i {
  padding-left: 10px;
  color: red;
}

.refreshing {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  animation: 0.5s rotate infinite linear;
}

@keyframes rotate {
  to {
    transform: rotate(1turn);
  }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>The HTML5 Herald</title>


  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <table class="main" style="width:100%">
    <tr>
      <th>product name</th>
      <th>number of product</th>
      <th>sales</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>product1</td>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>product2</td>
      <td>21</td>
      <td>94</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

</body>

</html>
```

The code can also be found on this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rfa5type/21/)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I set a rotation point for an element in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6652476/how-can-i-set-a-rotation-point-for-an-element-in-css)

Comment: no but comment below for Brandon answer my question. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the [`transform-origin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin) of `.refreshing`.

This is closer, but still not quite right: `transform-origin: 60% 40%;`

Comment: Thanks Brandon now works better. could you please explain what this transform-origin: 60% 40% do

Comment: You'll want to read the docs (link in my answer above), as they have a great visual tool. You can think of it like moving a "pin" in the element that tells where it rotates. If you put the pin at 0 0 (left: 0, top: 0), it will rotate around the top-left corner. My example above rotates the image around a point 60% from the left and 40% from the top.